# Replace Document Only If conditions are met - Atomic Revisioning of Documents

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the latest C# driver for mongoDB and the latest mongoDB server.

I have a class named User such that each user has and ID number and a revision indicator that indicates its current revision. In my app i'm receiving a stream of users from a queue and I would like to perform the following:

1. If user not exists by it's ID - Insert It.
2. If user exists by it's ID - Replace it only if the user revision is bigger from the user revision saved in the DB.

A) I also need all of that to happen **atomically** - such that it work in an environment where many threads upserts users into the Mongo DB.

B) I'm sure this will slow down the writes to the DB, but i expect it not to kill the DB write performance completely.

C)last requirement - It also should work in a case where my DB is a cluster of mongo nodes and not just single DB instance.

I was thinking about FindOneAndReplace with upsert == true, but the problem is that if the filter fails on the revision condition I don't want it to perform the upsert.

Alternative is Read Before Write (Warning - Ugly Stuff Below):

```
var savedUser = usersCollection.Find(p => p.UserId == userToSave.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
if (savedUser == null)
{                
       try
       {                    
           usersCollection.InsertOne(userToSave);
       }
       catch (MongoWriteException ex)
       {
          if (ex.WriteError.Category == ServerErrorCategory.DuplicateKey)
          {
            //Conditional Replace
            usersCollection.FindOneAndReplace<User>(p => p.UserId == userToSave.UserId 
           && p.Revision< userToSave.Revision, userToSave, 
           new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<User, User>() { IsUpsert = false });
          }
          else
          {
             throw;
          }
       }
 }
 else
 {
    //Conditional Replace
    if (savedUser.Revision < userToSave.Revision)
        usersCollection.FindOneAndReplace<User>(p => 
          p.UserId == userToSave.UserId && p.Revision < userToSave.Revision, 
          userToSave, 
          new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<User, User>() { IsUpsert = false });
 }
```

Note: I guess it will be more efficient to check for user existence by count instead of reading the entire user to the app.

Any Ideas?